# How to disable announcer?

Tags: accessibility

After I installed ubuntu, I have a voice reading out everything to me - a screen reader. I tried to find why it's starting and how to disable it, but don't know what it might be called.

One thing I can tell - when I kill the `init` process I was logged out and when I logged in again it disappeared.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 8):

It is happening becouse you have  enabled the  **Orca Screen Reader** .

To disable it go to **System settings** -> **Universal Acess** and disable the Screen Reader .

[image: orca]

You can also disbale it by editing `/etc/xdg/autostart/orca-autostart.desktop`

- Open it using `gksudo gedit 
  /etc/xdg/autostart/orca-autostart.desktop`
- Now change the `NoDisplay` to `false`

  ```
  NoDisplay=false
  ```